# when should I call the Focus method in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have several textboxes on my view. One of them needs to get focus. Which one exactly is defined in the data model. Currently I call the Focus method right after binding is done. I get false as a result which means the focus cannot be set. Question is

- what is right time for doing this?
- how do I know this moment being in the view model without knowing about the view anything?

Comment: Have you tried doing it after the first LayoutUpdated? That's a good point at which you know all the controls have done initializing themselves. There's lot of ways to bind an event to the view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is to schedule setting the focus via Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. It means the view model has to have a reference to the Dispatcher object which is somewhat tricky to do but worth the effort.